Kotlin: any sugar to initialize a value at local scope only once, like a static local in C?
Is there any sugar in Kotlin to initialize a value at local scope only once, like a static local in C? Or equivalently, to have a value at global or class scope, that is declared and used liked a local?
I have some lambda that uses data that only needs to be initialized once:
enum class Type { GOOD, BAD, UGLY }

class Job(val state: Type, val foo: Foo) {}

// Given a list of Jobs, sort it in Type declaration order, then display it
fun displayJobs(jobs: List<Job>) {
   textView.text = jobs.sortedBy { it -> 
     val order = Type.entries.withIndex().associate { (i, v) -> Pair(v, i) }
     order.get(it.state)!! 
   }
}

I want order to be in the scope of the lambda, because that's the only place it's used. But that means it gets redundantly re-calculated on every call to the lambda. For a lambda passed to sort, that's going to be n log n function calls and copies of the Map!
I can move it out to the function scope, but then it's still getting recalculated each time the function is called:
enum class Type { GOOD, BAD, UGLY }

fun displayJobs(jobs: List<Job>) {
   val order = Type.entries.withIndex().associate { (i, v) -> Pair(v, i) }

   textView.text = jobs.sortedBy { it -> 
     order.get(it.state)!! 
   }
}

I can move order to some top-level scope or a companion object, and have it calculated once, but now it's far away from its use site.
I can put order into the enum Class, but I have to be able to declare a companion object:
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumOrder() 
   = enumValues<T>().withIndex().associate { (i, v) -> Pair(v, i) }

enum class Type { GOOD, BAD, UGLY; 
   companion object {
       val order = enumOrder<Type>()
   }
}

This "caches" order into a val, so it's not recalculated, and it's accessed in a unsurprising way:
fun displayJobs(jobs: List<Job>) {

   textView.text = jobs.sortedBy { it -> 
     Type.order.get(it.state)!! 
   }
}

So yay!! problem solved!
Except...
For an enum I don't own, I can't add a companion object, can I?
I can attach an extension property to the class:
val KClass<Type>.order get() = enumValues<Type>().withIndex().associate { (i, v) -> Pair(v, i) }

textView.text = jobs.sortedBy { it -> 
     Type::class.order.get(it.state)!! 
   }

But extension properties don't allocate memory, so the get() gets called every time the lambda is run: we're right back to where we started!
Type.entries.sortedBy { Type::class.order.get(it)!! }

calls the function four times.
So again, does Kotlin offer something like C's static modifier? Note that lazy doesn't answer this, in:
fun displayJobs(jobs: List<Job>) {
   textView.text = jobs.sortedBy { it -> 
     val order by lazy { Type.entries.withIndex().associate { (i, v) -> Pair(v, i) } }
     order.get(it.state)!! 
   }
}

order gets (lazily) created each time the lambda gets called by sortedBy, which again is proportional to the number of elements to sort.

Does this help? Make displayJobs an object.

I hope I understand the problem right.
How about skipping building the enum pair, and directly using the ordinal property? E.g.,
listOf(Job(UGLY, ..), Job(BAD, ..), Job(GOOD, ..))
  .sortedBy { it.state.ordinal })

Should give you the jobs in order: GOOD, BAD and UGLY.

Yes, that works for this particular case, and I should have used a better motivating example, but I'm looking for an answer to the more general case.
